# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.spi.ReloadStrategy

Tags: apache-camel, consul, spring-camel

**I am migrating from 2.x.x Apache Camel to 3.2.0 Apache Camel version which is integrated with Spring, but while running the code i am getting the following error
**

```
2023-08-01 11:32:17.631 [ERROR] [SpringApplication.java -821] - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration.camelContext
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:748) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) [spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at accountService.Service.main(Service.java:35) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[?:1.8.0_371]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:246) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:239) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:229) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:182) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:157) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/spi/ReloadStrategy
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_371]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[?:1.8.0_371]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:246) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:239) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:229) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:182) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:157) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.spi.ReloadStrategy
```

**i have update camel-core2.25.4 to camel-core3.2.0 version and im getting error while running app
**

In our current project we using Java 8, Spring boot 2.7.12 with Apache Camel 2.25.4 Team is planning to upgrade camel to 3.2.X because it has the support for java 8. I saw the camel documentation which states that java 8 support will be discarded from 3.4.X version onward but struggle to find out compatible version of spring boot version required to use with camel 3.4.X
Do i need to upgrade the spring boot version? and if yes which version would be it or where i can find out.

in RouteBuilder config class inside  configure method

```
package accountService;

import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.consul.ConsulConfiguration;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel;
import org.apache.camel.model.cloud.ConsulServiceCallServiceDiscoveryConfiguration;
import org.apache.camel.model.cloud.ServiceCallConfigurationDefinition;

import org.apache.camel.spring.boot.cloud.CamelCloudConfigurationProperties.ServiceDiscovery;
import org.apache.camel.spring.boot.cloud.CamelCloudConfigurationProperties.ServiceDiscoveryConfiguration;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import errorhandlers.CustomException;



@Component
public class BuilderService extends RouteBuilder{
    
    
    @Value("${currentEnv.port}")
    int port;
    
    @Value("${currentEnv.host}")
    String host;
    
    @Value("${consul.serviceRegUrl}")
    String consulRegUrl;
    
    @Value("${consul.serviceDeregUrl}")
    String consulDeRegUrl;
    
    @Value("${kafka.kafkaReq}")
    String kafkaReq;
    
    @Value("${currentEnv.minThread}")
    String minThread;
    
    @Value("${currentEnv.maxThread}")
    String maxThread;
    
    @Value("${consul.url}")
    String url;

    @Autowired
    CamelContext context;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
    
        ServiceCallConfigurationDefinition sep = new ServiceCallConfigurationDefinition();
        ConsulServiceCallServiceDiscoveryConfiguration con = sep.consulServiceDiscovery();
        con.setUrl(url);
        sep.setComponent("jetty");
        
    camelContext.setServiceCallConfiguration(sep);
    
        restConfiguration().component("jetty").host(host).port(port).endpointProperty("minThreads", minThread)
        .endpointProperty("maxThreads", maxThread).enableCORS(true).endpointProperty("bridgeEndpoint", "true");
     
        from("direct:start").routeId("SERVICE")
          .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("PUT"))
          .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
          .to(consulRegUrl);
        //from("direct:stop").shutdownRunningTask(ShutdownRunningTask.CompleteAllTasks)
        from("direct:stop").setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("PUT"))
          .toD(consulDeRegUrl+"/${header.id}");
        
        
    }

}
```